# Configure single entity with multiple datasource connections

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entity, datasource

I'm currently working on creating DB connections using the jpa repository in springboot. And I connected to two data sources for two different connections on single DB(mySQL) as shown below.

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = null;
        try {
            dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("mpfp.db.write.driver"));
            dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("mpfp.db.write.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("mpfp.db.write.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("mpfp.db.write.password"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            UtilityLogger.genericError("Exception occurred in dataSource bean configuration: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = null;
        try {
            dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.read.driverClassName"));
            dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.read.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.read.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.read.password"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            UtilityLogger.genericError("Exception occurred in dataSource bean configuration: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return dataSource;
    }
```

And I'll create the entity for connecting to the data source. This is where my problem comes. **How would I tell my entity to use the particular data source??**. So that I can implement the queries for particular data connection as per my requirement.

As I'm very new to hibernate and jpa repository any kind of help is so appreciated.

Comment: what so you meant by this " I would I tell my entity to use the particular data source"

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo mistake.

Comment: You don't tell your entity which data sources to use. It is the other way. You tell your datasources which entity to use. So it should not be a problem to use same entity with two datasources